# Seconds to date and time format

Tags: asp.net

In c#, how can I convert seconds to date and time format.The date and time format is as follows. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS . I had time in seconds not in milliseconds. I want to convert 1365004800 to 2013-04-03 16:00:00

Comment: 1365004800  this number is a second ??? You want to convert big second's to date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below code

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0); //Set default date 1/1/1970
date = date.AddSeconds(1365004800); //add seconds
label1.Text = date.ToString(); //Display result 2013-04-03 16:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

So the C# to convert Unix Time, (which is what you have) to a date time is:

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToNormalDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
{
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Then format the date accordingly with [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) in C#.